# How to refresh listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have used `ListView` added and delete option but when i clicked delete button database value is deleted but `ListView` is not refreshed. I have put

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but the list doesn't refresh.

Comment: Can you provide some java code?

Comment: Lot of incorrect answers here. Just use `adapter.remove(item)` or `adapter.add(item)`, it will work fine, no need to call other methods.

Comment: I have also faced this problem..to solve it, the work around I did was to  simply reinitialize the adapter and again set listView (eg., listView.setAdpater(adapter)) and it worked fine.

Comment: Rekha what you said i can't understand? Please let me know briefly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `runOnUiThread`.

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

UI is update outside the main thread. Put all the logic inside an `asynctask` and in postexecute, call the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `.invalidate();` on the ListView to tell the framework the the view is outdated and should be redrawen!